# Trajectory of a point

Tags: trigonometry

A point is moving in an orthogonal axis system $xOy$.

On the X - axis the motion is described by the equation :
$$ x(t) = A \cdot \sin(\omega\cdot t + \phi_1) $$
On the Y - axis the motion is described by the equation :
$$ y(t) = B \cdot \sin(\omega\cdot t + \phi_2)$$

How can I find the equation for the trajectory? Also what values should $\phi_1,\phi_2$ have in order for the trajectory to be a line, $A$ and $B$ are known.

Comment: yes, but i don't actually understand how to find it

Comment: thanks i'll do , but do you any mathematical way of finding the equation of its trajectory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this. One idea is to get rid of the parametric variable $t$ and solve for $y$ in terms of $x$. You can do this by finding $t$ in terms of $x$:

$$
\begin{align*}
t &= \frac{\arcsin(x/A) - \phi_1} {\omega}.
\end{align*}
$$
This expression for $t$ can be substituted in the expression for $y$ to get:

$$
\begin{align*}
y &= B \sin(\omega t + \phi_2)\\ 
  &= B \sin\left(\omega \cdot \frac{\arcsin(x/A) - \phi_1} {\omega} + \phi_2 \right)\\ 
  &= B \sin\left(\arcsin(x/A) + \phi_2 - \phi_1 \right).
\end{align*}
$$

Perhaps you can try working from here? What value of $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ would make this a straight line? Hint: $\sin(\arcsin(x)) = x$.

Comment: thanks it really helped